# Changing App Icon Source from Info.plist?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, info.plist

Is there a way to change what app icon is loaded based on a value from Info.plist?

Currently my app has a few configurations and I'd like the Debug version to have one icon and the Release one a different icon.

This might be an assumption, but as the LaunchScreen is present in the Info.plist under UILaunchStoryboardName, I'm thinking that the app icon should be present too. Apple doesn't provide a full list of all the keys available in Info.plist.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/105641/change-app-icon-build-time

Comment: Awesome, thanks @mttrb. Your comment wouldn't qualify for an answer, would it?